# Schwarz Lemma with a pole at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m practicing old qualifying exam questions, and I am stuck on this one. We are given $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$ = {$z : |z| > 2$}, $f$ maps $\Omega$ to $\Omega$, and $f$ has a pole at infinity. We are asked to prove $|f(z)| \geq |z|$ for $z \in \Omega$.

My thinking is if we define $\displaystyle g = \frac{1}{f(\frac{2}{z})}$, then g satisfies the conditions for the Schwarz Lemma, giving us that $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ for $z \in D_1(0)$. If we then let $w = \frac{2}{z}$, we have:

\begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{1}{f(w)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{2}{w}\right| \\
    \implies |w| \leq |2f(w)| 
\end{align*}

For $w \in \Omega$, since $\frac{2}{w}: D_1(0) \rightarrow \Omega$.

So I seem to be off by a factor of 2. I’m sure I’m making some mistake, and probably a fundamental one at that, so if anyone can offer some guidance, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: You seem to be missing a hypothesis; as written you could scale $f$ arbitrarily.

Comment: If this is true then $|\frac  1n f(z)| \ge |z|$ also, which is absurd.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I very much missed one of the assumptions. We are also given that $f$ maps $\Omega$ to itself, which I've edited in the main post to reflect that. Any idea on how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. The key is that $\displaystyle \frac{2}{z}$ is its own inverse. So if we think of the map:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{2}{z} \circ f \circ \frac{2}{z}
\end{align*}

Then **this** satisfies the Schwarz Lemma. The function $g$ I defined earlier does too, but I believe that specifically maps to $D_{0.5}(0)$. The extra 2 then cancels with the 2 I was getting previous, yielding the result.

If someone could verify this, that would be a big help. I think it works, but I've also never done a Schwarz lemma with maps that are analytic only on the Riemann Sphere like $\displaystyle \frac{2}{z}$

Comment: Looks good to me. Seems like your original $g = 1/f(2/z)$ maps into $D_{1/2}(0)$ and we can show such maps satisfy $|g(z)| \leq |z/2|$ since $2g$ maps into $D_1(0)$ so then the Schwarz Lemma implies $|2g(z)| \leq |z|$. Of course, your answer is more efficient since $g(z) = \frac{2}{f(2/z)}$ does all this in one step.

Comment: @JakeZweifler Right, that is exactly what I noticed I was doing. My issue was I didn't realize I was mapping into $D_{0.5}(0)$, but it should have been obvious since I used $\displaystyle \frac{2}{z}$ to go from $\Omega$ to the unit disk in the first place. Thanks!